# Python 2.7.3 not working in Mavericks Terminal :(

Tags: python, terminal, osx-mavericks

so i upgraded to Mavericks hoping that my scripts would be fine . . . luckily when I run my scripts in Coderunner they work . i do simple test scripts in the terminal because its easy and i like the way it looks.  i'm not sure why the frameworks work in coderunner but not the terminal.

does anyone have any idea how to fix this ?

[image]

[image]

i tried updating the software and got the same error

```
Last login: Wed Oct 30 11:08:51 on ttys000
opus-magnum:~ Opus_Magnum$ python
Python 2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = 'hello'
>>> print s
Segmentation fault: 11
opus-magnum:~ Opus_Magnum$
```

`

Comment: i don't think this deserves a down vote. i think a lot of people experienced this issue and if the scripts work in another interpreter then i feel like it is a valid question.

Comment: It's off-topic, as it's more a software installation problem.

Comment: @chepner i see your point but i thought it was alright since "Q: python setup.py uninstall " software installation question has 165 up votes

Comment: I don't know which question you are referring to, but it may have both referred to *writing* a setup.py file, as well as being an older question, from a time when standards for what was and wasn't on-topic were much different than today. (BTW, just my opinion; I neither up- nor downvoted.)

Comment: it does not belong here, ask apple

Comment: FWIW, this is a known issue that's been discussed on the python-dev mailing list. Apple's using a new version of libedit that breaks a workaround for a longstanding bug.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue18458

Comment: Apart from that: this is not the Apple system Python on Mavericks (which is 2.7.5).

Comment: @JohnJohn2 i updated to version 2.7.5 and got the same error.  should i just delete the question so it stops getting down votes or is that worst than the down votes on this site?

Comment: It is a [known issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue18458)

Answer (score 3):

You are not running the correct version of python that was released with OS X Mavericks.

```
[1:17pm][wlynch@watermelon ~] /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```